# Hive : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: sql, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from 
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask error while inserting
>   record into hive table.

`select * from tablename` is working fine.

Am i need to add any property in hive-site.xml?

Comment: would you please put code here for other people's review?

Comment: insert command please

Comment: @abhiieor  insert into table student values('abc', 1);

Comment: @TKHN please find the above sample query.

Comment: Return code `1` typically means "could not start YARN container, inspect YARN logs" while return code `2` means "internal error, inspect YARN logs". So please **inspect the YARN logs** for that job. Hive displays the job ID in the form `application_000000000_0000`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to insert partitioned table.
set below property before inserting.

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=10000;
set hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=1000;
```